# Powershell find string from console and turn it into if statement

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to run a job in Jenkins from powershell and I need it to search for a string like Finished : FAILED and use that in an if statement to send an email if it failed. Here is what I have so far

```
$jobResult = java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://MYJENKINSSERVER/ build 'Test - Run Inventory Load' -s -v |Select-String -Pattern 'Finished: FAILED' 

if ($jobResult = $null)  
{
  //my email code will go here(already have it) }
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to accomplish it seeing that string and saying oh yeah it failed and need to email

Comment: `if($jobResult -eq $null)`

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks!!